# Random bug that happens randomly

Tags: batch-file

Just coding an OS with this code:

```
@echo off

:boot
echo.
echo                                                     :!!.                      Time: %time%
echo                                                   :!7^.                       Date: %date%
echo                                      ..         :!7^                              
echo                                     Y??Y   :?YJJ?:                                
echo                                     J77? ^JGGPPG!                                 
echo                                        ^YGBGGG5!                                  
echo                                      ~YGGGGGY~                                    
echo                                   .!5GGGBGJ^                                      
echo                                   ?BBGBGJ^                                        
echo                                   .~Y5?:                                          
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Welcome %username% !
set /p input1 = Password:
if %input1% == 12345678 goto menu
goto boot

:menu
cls
echo.
echo                                                     :!!.                      Time: %time%
echo                                                   :!7^.                       Date: %date%
echo                                      ..         :!7^                              
echo                                     Y??Y   :?YJJ?:                                
echo                                     J77? ^JGGPPG!                                 
echo                                        ^YGBGGG5!                                  
echo                                      ~YGGGGGY~                                    
echo                                   .!5GGGBGJ^                                      
echo                                   ?BBGBGJ^                                        
echo                                   .~Y5?:                                          
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Main menu
echo 1. Notepad
echo 2. Watch movies
echo 3. Calculator
echo 4. System info
echo 5. Chat
echo 6. Reboot
echo 7. Shutdown
set /p input2=/
if %input2% == 1 goto notepad
if %input2% == 2 goto movies
if %input2% == 3 goto calculator
if %input2% == 4 goto info
if %input2% == 5 goto chat
if %input2% == 6 goto boot
if %input2% == 7 exit
goto menu
```

then some error popped up on the terminal of the coding window

how do i fix this error?

im using vscode

like it seems nothing wrong with the code

error: goto was unexpected at this time

either what i type the password it just show the same error

Comment: Your problem is that spaces are significant in a `set` command. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N". When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will close if a syntax-error is found or the script runs to completion. You *can* put a `pause` after statements and home in on the error, but better to [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any (error) messages will be displayed.

Comment: **Do not use `Set /P` for your end user to select a known single key entry from a given list**. There is a `choice.exe` utility included in all modern Windows OSs for exactly that purpose. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key to see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example script based upon your submission and the comments offered:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

GoTo Boot

:Logo
ClS
Echo(
Echo                                        :!!.         Time: %TIME%
Echo                                      :!7^^.          Date: %DATE%
Echo                         ..         :!7^^
Echo                        Y??Y   :?YJJ?:
Echo                        J77? ^^JGGPPG!
Echo                           ^^YGBGGG5!
Echo                         ~YGGGGGY~
Echo                      .!5GGGBGJ^^
Echo                      ?BBGBGJ^^
Echo                      .~Y5?:
Echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GoTo :EOF

:Boot
Call :Logo
Echo Welcome %UserName%.
Set "inPass="
Set /P "inPass=Password>" || GoTo Boot
Set inPass | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /XLIC:"inpass=12345678" 1>NUL
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo Boot

:Menu
Call :Logo
Echo Main menu
Echo 1. Notepad
Echo 2. Watch movies
Echo 3. Calculator
Echo 4. System info
Echo 5. Chat
Echo 6. Reboot
Echo 7. Shutdown
Echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 1234567
If ErrorLevel 7 (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\shutdown.exe /S
    GoTo :EOF
)
If ErrorLevel 6 (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\shutdown.exe /R
    GoTo :EOF
)
If ErrorLevel 5 GoTo Chat
If ErrorLevel 4 (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\systeminfo.exe /Fo List
    Pause
    GoTo Menu
)
If ErrorLevel 3 (
    Start %SystemRoot%\System32\calc.exe
    GoTo Menu
)
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Movies
Start %SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe
GoTo Menu

:Chat
Echo(
Echo(Let us chat.
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1>NUL
GoTo Menu

:Movies
Echo(
Echo(Get the popcorn, it is movie time.
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1>NUL
GoTo Menu
```

I have used a more robust way of using `Set /P`, the `choice.exe` command line utility, `Call`'s, `GoTo`'s, and direct commands, in order to offer different ways of doing this. You should also note, because the caret, `^` is a special character, I have had to double those up, *(escape them)*, in order that your image included the ones you wanted to display.